# Pip install playsound not working requirements to build wheel error

Tags: python, pip

I have attempted to pip install playsound and this error comes up everytime

```
 Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qx_7x6an\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qx_7x6an\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qx_7x6an\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qx_7x6an\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1262, in getsource
          lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1244, in getsourcelines      
          lines, lnum = findsource(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\jamje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1081, in findsource
          raise OSError('could not get source code')
      OSError: could not get source code
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

It is really annoying. I tried using `pip install docx` nothing either.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel`